# Sum of even Fibonacci

Tags: java

I am not sure why my code produces a wrong negative value when I put 4000000 into the method's parameter size, i.e. fib(4000000)?

The question asks:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

My first code:

```
public void fib(int k) {

    int result = 0;
    int[] array = new int[k];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
 
    for (int i = 2; i < k; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i - 2] + array[i - 1];       
    }
 
    for (int even: array) {
        
        if (even % 2 == 0) {
            result += even;
        }
    }        
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Which didn't work so I assumed it was because the array size was too big (four million is a lot) thus I tried to write a different code:

```
public void fib(int k) {
    
    int sum = 0;
    int term1 = 1;
    int term2 = 2;
    int term3 = 0;
    int i = 2;
    
    while (i < k) {
        
        term3 = term1 + term2;
        
        term1 = term2;
        term2 = term3;
        i++;
        
        if (term2 % 2 == 0) {
            sum += term2;
        }
    }   
    
    System.out.println(sum + 2);
    
}
```

Which also didn't work.

What is wrong with my code? For small numbers of `size` it works but for large it doesn't.

After I googled the answer to the question I found:

```
    int term1 = 1;
    int term2 = 2;
    int i = 0;
    int result = 0;

    while (term1 < 4000000) {
        i = term1;
        term1 = term2;
        term2 = term2 + i;
        
        if (term2 % 2 == 0) {
            result += term2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```

which works.

Comment: Likely overflow. Try to use long instead

Comment: Googled answer works because that is a different question and scenario. In this solution you are summing numbers in Fibonacci with values less than 4million which would be less but in your original solution you are adding first 4million fibbonacu numbers which would be larger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're running into an overflow issue. I think you're reading the problem slightly incorrectly. It says you should look at all Fibonacci numbers where the value of the number is <= 4 million. Instead, you're looking at the *first 4 million* Fibonacci numbers. It's the difference between this:

> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 (all fib numbers less than 10)

and this:

> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 (the first 10 fib numbers)

I think it wants the former, but you're doing the latter.

Instead of doing:

```
while (i < k) {
```

What if you do this?

```
while (term1 < k) {
```

Comment: You're right! Fml, I spent three hours trying to figure out what was going wrong. Lol thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

As per [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> By default, the int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement
>   integer, which has a minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of
>   2^31-1.

You are storing the sum in `result` which is an int and it will overflow. Reaplce it with long as below and it will work:

```
public static void fib(int size) {

        long result = 0;
        int[] array = new int[size];
        array[0] = 1;
        array[1] = 2;

        for (int i = 2; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i - 2] + array[i - 1];
        }

        for (int even: array) {
            if (even % 2 == 0) {
                result += even;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

And the value for `fib(4000000)` is now `2111290219918`. The signed long has a minimum value of `-2^63` and a maximum value of `2^63-1`.

Comment: I have tried it in IntelliJ before posting answer :)

Comment: It game me 2111290219918 but the answer is 4613732.

Comment: Then probably you need to check the logic.